# How to successfully create a function that creates an object and returns a pointer to that object?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, reference

There exists this function when working with Direct2d:

```
HRESULT WINAPI D2D1CreateFactory(
  _In_      D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE factoryType,
  _In_      REFIID riid,
  _In_opt_  const D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS *pFactoryOptions,
  _Out_     void **ppIFactory
);
```

When the above method returns, ppIFactory contains the address to a pointer to the new factory and so it is possible to use this factory.

I wanted to do something alike, so I did this into MessageLog.h:

```
void CreateMessageLog(MessageLog**);

class MessageLog{
public:
    void PutToLog(WCHAR[]);

    WCHAR* GetLog();
    int GetLogLenght();
    int GetnLogLines();

private:
    WCHAR logHistory[MaxLogSize];
    int nLogLines;
};
```

And this into MessageLog.cpp:

```
void CreateMessageLog(MessageLog** ppMessageLog)
{
    MessageLog mLog;
    MessageLog* pmLog=&mLog;
    ppMessageLog=&pmLog;
}
```

Now that this is done, I have a few problem. First of all, once the CreateMessageLog function is over, the created MessageLog object will be out of scope and the pointer will become NULL right? What is a solution to this problem?

By the way, I guess my CreateMessageLog function won't do what I expect it to do. What is the solution to that problem too? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic allocation:

```
MessageLog* CreateMessageLog()
{
    return new MessageLog;
}
```

and outside remember to `delete` the pointer created by `new` inside the function.
You'll be able to access the memory pointed from the pointer for all the time you need. When you are done with it you have to free the memory manually by calling `delete a`:

Example:

```
MessageLog* a = createMessageLog();
// use `a` the way you want
// when done:
delete a;
```

You could also create a copy if the `MessageLog` object is not huge. Even if it's less efficient, you don't have to manage the memory yourself:

```
MessageLog CreateMessageLog()
{
    MessageLog a;
    return a;
}
```

PS: Be sure the copy constructor is available.

Comment: Does that mean that an object dynamically created will still exist after the function is over, until it is deleted?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron, it will be available until **you** decide you are done with it and call `delete *ppMessageLog`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write like this

```
void CreateMessageLog(MessageLog** ppMessageLog)
{
    MessageLog mLog;
    MessageLog* pmLog=&mLog;
    ppMessageLog=&pmLog;
}
```

the MessaLog is created on the stack and has function scope, it ceases to exist the moment you leave CreateMessageLog

Create the MessageLog using the heap instead

```
void CreateMessageLog(MessageLog** ppMessageLog)
{
    MessageLog* mLog = new MessageLog;
    *ppMessageLog=pmLog;
}
```

don't forget to delete the allocated heap when you no longer need it.